# Drawing Inner Shadow with CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I know that you can use CGContextSetShadow to draw a drop shadow, but is there any way to draw an inner shadow?

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer/5542116#5542116 it shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This implies that what you're drawing has an interior to view the shadow through. I further presume that you don't want the shadow to appear *outside* what you're drawing.

So, clip to the outline of what you're drawing, and then draw with shadow as normal.