# iPhone view layering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a pretty abstract question, because I'm not sure exactly how to ask it. I have a UIImageView on one of my views. I want to have the imageview look "pressed into the superview". I'm not sure what the technical term is, but I want it to look 3D and like the imageview has been pressed into the page. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want it engraved into the superview? Create a "frame" decorative image in Photoshop, Gimp, … and add it to your interface. Google "photoshop engraved frame" for hundreds of results.

Comment: There's no way to do this using the iOS SDK?

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer