# Inner shadow in UIView (UIImageView)

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, core-graphics

I would like to achieve inner shadows on the border of an UIView. See screenshot

[image: See attached screenshot].

I have tried it using shadow CALayer, but it does not seem to be good choice for this. Thanks for any hints.

Unfortunately I did not find an answer in the topics discussed here.

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer

Answer (score 1):

I always do this with a UIImage that has the inner shadow in it, and lay that on top of the view you're trying to shadow.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the image which is as shadow overlay have to be transparent. This is not good for performance in UITableView.

Comment: On any modern device it won't be an issue

Comment: i can say that using a second image as "effect overlay" above another image could be sometimes even better than layer effects considering the performance issues.