# Depressed UITableView like twitter app

Tags: objective-c, ios, photoshop

I'm trying to replicate cells like the following image of the Twitter app. Could somebody provide insight into how you might do this, including an explanation of how you might create a custom view of the image in Photoshop if that were necessary and if this could not be done programmatically. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You want the "depressed" cells to be available only if there is an error? or maybe you already know how to do that and your question in ONLY about the looks?

Comment: yea my question is only about the looks, and not even about the little middle arrow. It's entirely about how to create this shadow effect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is only about the looks... All you need to do is create a custom `UITableViewCell` and override the drawing function to draw an inner-shadow (like on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer)).

That, however, will not produce the "dent" on the middle.

Comment: As for the link you posted, how would you modify that code to be suitable for ios/where would you put that code if I want it to show up in a uitableviewcell? Thanks.