# Create an inner shadow effect in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, shadow, quartz-2d

**I'm trying to apply an inner shadow like in the Apple Reminder app** (see in particular the Lists table view).

[image]

I would like to do the drawing using Quartz instead of using an UIImageView. 
The main problem is that if I override drawRect of the UITableView the result of the drawing will be overlapped by the table cells and won't be visible, the same trying to add a new CALayer to the table.

How would you recreate this effect?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602529/inner-shadow-on-uitableview-layer

Comment: I've already see these examples but they are referring to a static UIView and not a scrollable view like a tableview, or at least they add an additional view to create the shadow, thing that I possibly wanted to avoid

Comment: Can't you use an image like in the picture to your background and make your TableView transparent? I have personally used that method in my apps.