# How to make a UIView shadow stretch when device is rotated?

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow, autoresizingmask

In a custom tableview cell, I'm drawing a simple rectangle with a shadow like this:

```
photoBorder = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, self.frame.size.width-8, 190)] autorelease];
photoBorder.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
photoBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
photoBorder.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
photoBorder.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
photoBorder.layer.shadowRadius = 4;
photoBorder.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
photoBorder.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
photoBorder.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
photoBorder.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:photoBorder.bounds].CGPath; // this line seems to be causing the problem
```

This works fine when the view first loads. However, when you rotate the device, the shadow stays the same size. I'd really like it to stretch to the new width of "photoBorder".

I can get it to work by removing the shadowPath, but the tableview takes a noticeable performance hit.

Anyone have any tips on making a shadow, on a UIView, that can stretch, without losing performance?

Answer (score 6):

After searching for a few hours and not finding anything, I posted this. Then found an answer a few minutes later.

The simple solution for me appears to be simply moving the shadowPath into layoutSubviews.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    photoBorder.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:photoBorder.bounds].CGPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a subclass of UIView so that you can get the new bounds in the `layoutSubviews()` method.

Note: If you try to add this code in a ViewController that owns the subview, the bounds will remain static as you rotate, which results in the wrong shadowPath.

```
import UIKit

class BackgroundView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateShadow(on: self)
    }

    func updateShadow(on background: UIView) {
        let layer = background.layer
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: background.bounds).cgPath
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        layer.shadowRadius = 4
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.22
    }

}
```

1. Make sure you call `super.layoutSubviews()` to handle any Auto Layout constraints.
2. You can set a custom class in a Storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

for performance enhancement you can draw an inner shadow using Core Graphics.

[Inner shadow effect on UIView layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer)