# inner shadow on top and bottom of UITextView

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitextview

I'am kind of new in IOS development, i want to create shadow on top and bottom of UITexView, basically the shadow will appear when people scrolling..

any help really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I would say searching for a solution before asking seems like a better approach to this problem.

[Inner shadow effect on UIView layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer)

[Scrolling inner shadow on UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653672/scrolling-inner-shadow-on-uitextview)

[How to style UITextview to like Rounded Rect text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field)

Comment: hi @jehanzeb-malik thanks for replay, i already check your link but what i'am looking for is the shadow only visible on UITextView when people scrolling..

Answer (score 0):

Use Core-Graphics, here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2079/core-graphics-101-shadows-and-gloss)