# How to create rounded UITextField with inner shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm customizing a `UITextfield` to look like a `UISearchbar`.

I do something like

```
self.back_textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 7, 310, 30)];
[self.back_textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
self.back_textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
```

But I see this:

[image]

As you can see the inner shadow doesn't follow the border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess background on a `UITextField` is an Image, so it no follow to your corner radius.
Creating inner shadow is tricky in iOS. You have 2 options.
1) Use image as background for `UITextField`
2) Set the shadow programmatically (but it look less attractive than option 1).

Here is the code for setting rounded inner shadow for textfield with [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436615/881989) from @Matt Wilding

```
_textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;

CAShapeLayer* shadowLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[shadowLayer setFrame:_textField.bounds];

// Standard shadow stuff
[shadowLayer setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
[shadowLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
[shadowLayer setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
[shadowLayer setShadowRadius:4];

// Causes the inner region in this example to NOT be filled.
[shadowLayer setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];

// Create the larger rectangle path.
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectInset(_textField.bounds, -42, -42));

// Add the inner path so it's subtracted from the outer path.
// someInnerPath could be a simple bounds rect, or maybe
// a rounded one for some extra fanciness.
CGPathRef someInnerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_textField.bounds cornerRadius:10.0f].CGPath;
CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, someInnerPath);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

[shadowLayer setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);

[[_textField layer] addSublayer:shadowLayer];

CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setPath:someInnerPath];
[shadowLayer setMask:maskLayer];
```

Don't forget to import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the shadow resizable? For example, increasing the uitextfield's width the shadow's width should increase.

Comment: Background image will be resized with the textfield. I think background image will be better solution.

Comment: Ok, but if I change a lot the size, the background does not deform?

Comment: I got it! Just use "resizableImageWithCapInsets"

Answer (score 4):

add `QuartzCore` FrameWork to your project

And add it in your **.m** file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and use

```
self.back_textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; // set as you per your requirement
self.back_textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 5.2f; // set as you per your requirement
```

Comment: That's good solution I use too. It's strange that Apple hasn't made it easier.