# How to control shadow spread and blur?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I have designed UI elements in sketch, and one of them has a shadow with blur 1 and spread 0. I looked at the doc for the views layer property and layer doesn't have anything named spread or blur, or anything equivalent (the only control was merely shadowOpacity). How can control things like blur and spread?

Here are my settings in Sketch:

[image: Sketch shadow settings]

And here is what I want my shadow to look like:

[image: Shadow wanted]

And here is what it looks like at the moment:

[image: Current shadow]

Note, you have to click on the picture to actually see the shadow.

My code is as follows:

```
func setupLayer(){
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    view.layer.shadowColor = Colors.Shadow.CGColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
}
```

Comment: The tags ios(the platform), design (the use of the software Sketch) and Core-Graphics (it's possible to use a UIBezierPath to draw the shadow, whih might be relevant) are all relevant, I don't see why they should be removed.

Comment: you want shadow for that white view only right?

Comment: Looks like Sketch and CoreAnimation framework have different metrics, because it always looks different on iOS and in Sketch with same params.

Comment: Ah. The joys of working with designers who use tools that bare little or no resemblance to the way iOS works. If you move to something like PaintCode instead of Sketch it will not only work like iOS works but it will give you the code you need too. :-)

Comment: What if you have set both the radius and the blur in sketch?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Here's how to apply all 6 Sketch shadow properties to a UIView's layer with near perfect accuracy:

```
extension CALayer {
  func applySketchShadow(
    color: UIColor = .black,
    alpha: Float = 0.5,
    x: CGFloat = 0,
    y: CGFloat = 2,
    blur: CGFloat = 4,
    spread: CGFloat = 0)
  {
    masksToBounds = false
    shadowColor = color.cgColor
    shadowOpacity = alpha
    shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
    shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
    if spread == 0 {
      shadowPath = nil
    } else {
      let dx = -spread
      let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
      shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
    }
  }
}
```

Say we want to represent the following:

[image]

You can easily do this via:

```
myView.layer.applySketchShadow(
  color: .black, 
  alpha: 0.5, 
  x: 0, 
  y: 0, 
  blur: 4, 
  spread: 0)
```

or more succinctly:

```
myView.layer.applySketchShadow(y: 0)
```

Example:

> [image]
>
> *Left: iPhone 8 UIView screenshot; right: Sketch rectangle.*

Note:

- When using a non-zero `spread`, it hardcodes a path based on the `bounds` of the CALayer. If the layer's bounds ever change, you'd want to call the `applySketchShadow()` method again.

Comment: Hm. In Sketch, if you apply spread, it 'moves out', where the blur/gradient of the shadow begins. Which means - it stays at the constant shadow-colour, until the blur begins. But if we move the shadowLayer around, the shadow would only begin from that layer, right? (Say spread is 10, the shadow would only begin after an offset of 10, where as in Sketch, the blur/gradient would begin after an offset of 10). So they don't really match up, right?

Comment: @Senseful I'm interested to know how you achieved this formula?!

Comment: I'm not sure this should be the accepted answer.  I testing this out, and there seem to be some cases where the shadows apply to the subviews instead of the view I actually add it to

Comment: You forgot to set `maskToBounds = false`.

Comment: How do you know that blur = 4 translates to shadowRadius 4 / 2.0 ? I would like to understand how they are related. Thank you.

Comment: As mentioned above by ScottyBlades, this won't work without `maskToBounds = false`. An example where it will fail is when applying this shadow to an `UIButton`.

Comment: @daredevil1234 `CALayer` shadows will _always_ be applied to rasterized layer contents, which includes all sublayers. If you want to exclude sublayers, you need to move the layer you want to apply a shadow to up in the hierarchy so it has no children and only has sibling layers. So it's more about how you structure your layers than it is an incorrect solution.

Comment: Should this be `shadowRadius = blur / UIScreen.main.scale` as opposed to hard-coding `blur / 2.0`? Or, is there another reason to divide by 2? @matchifang Did you figure this out?

Comment: Thanks! Maybe for better clarification x/y/blur should be named x/y/blurInPoints or x/y/blurInPixels, whatever is correct :)

Comment: Great simple and user-friendly solution! Thanx for all who participated in!

Comment: What's dx? I'm not seeing it defined anywhere

Answer (score 59):

You can try this .... you can play with the values.
The `shadowRadius` dictates the amount of blur. `shadowOffset` dictates where the shadow goes.

> Swift 2.0

```
let radius: CGFloat = demoView.frame.width / 2.0 //change it to .height if you need spread for height
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.1 * radius, height: demoView.frame.height))
//Change 2.1 to amount of spread you need and for height replace the code for height

demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
demoView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
demoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.4)  //Here you control x and y
demoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
demoView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
demoView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
demoView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
```

> Swift 3.0

```
let radius: CGFloat = demoView.frame.width / 2.0 //change it to .height if you need spread for height 
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.1 * radius, height: demoView.frame.height)) 
//Change 2.1 to amount of spread you need and for height replace the code for height

demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
demoView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
demoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.4)  //Here you control x and y
demoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
demoView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
demoView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
demoView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

> Example with spread

[image: Example with spread]

> To create a basic shadow

```
    demoView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    demoView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    demoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.5, 4.0); //Here your control your spread
    demoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5 
    demoView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //Here your control your blur
```

> Basic Shadow example in Swift 2.0

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: The information is wrong, offset is not a control of spread, it's a control of x and y.

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite i accidentally interchanged the comments i have updated the answers

Comment: Right, and now comes the core of my question: how do I control spread?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Updated code now change 2.1 to amount of spread you need

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here I am not able to understand shadowOpacity (why its is used).

Comment: @Sunita shadowOpacity sets how transparent the shadow is, where 0 is invisible and 1 is as strong as possible.

Comment: @O-mkar your answer still contains errors about spread. Fix it please

Answer (score 15):

**Sketch Shadow Using IBDesignable and IBInspectable in Swift 4**

> **SKETCH AND XCODE SIDE BY SIDE**

[image: Shadow Exampl]

> **CODE**

```
@IBDesignable class ShadowView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGPoint {
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: layer.shadowOffset.width, y:layer.shadowOffset.height)
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: newValue.x, height: newValue.y)
        }

     }

    @IBInspectable var shadowBlur: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue / 2.0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowSpread: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if shadowSpread == 0 {
                layer.shadowPath = nil
            } else {
                let dx = -shadowSpread
                let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
                layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **OUTPUT**

[image: DEMO OUTPUT]

> **HOW TO USE IT**

[image: DEMO]

Comment: Shouldn't you return `layer.shadowRadius * 2` for shadowBlur getter

Comment: yo why you multiply or divide shadow radius? can someone please explain

Answer (score 8):

This code worked very well for me:

```
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2 // opacity, 20%
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 2 // HALF of blur
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2) // Spread x, y
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: The blur value in Sketch does **not** match Core Animation's shadow radius.

Comment: What ended up working close enough for us was halving the blur value in Sketch for Core Animation's shadow radius.

Comment: spread and offset are different params. Don't get people confused!

Answer (score 3):

For those who are attempting to apply a shadow to a predefined path (Like for a circular view, for instance), here's what I ended up with:

```swift
extension CALayer {
    func applyShadow(color: UIColor = .black,
                     alpha: Float = 0.5,
                     x: CGFloat = 0,
                     y: CGFloat = 2,
                     blur: CGFloat = 4,
                     spread: CGFloat = 0,
                     path: UIBezierPath? = nil) {
        shadowColor = color.cgColor
        shadowOpacity = alpha
        shadowRadius = blur / 2
        if let path = path {
            if spread == 0 {
                shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
            } else {
                let scaleX = (path.bounds.width + (spread * 2)) / path.bounds.width
                let scaleY = (path.bounds.height + (spread * 2)) / path.bounds.height

                path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: x + -spread, y: y + -spread).scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: scaleY))
                shadowPath = path.cgPath
            }
        } else {
            shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
            if spread == 0 {
                shadowPath = nil
            } else {
                let dx = -spread
                let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
                shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
            }
        }
        shouldRasterize = true
        rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

I'll post some examples later, but this has worked spot on for circular views for me.

Comment: This "almost" works but the spread is wrong when you use a spread of `1` with `x` and `y` `0` `shapeLayer.applyShadow(color: .black, alpha: 1, x: 0, y: 0, blur: 0, spread: 1, path: path)`. In this case the shadow has an offset while it should not. Here the triangle should have the shadow spread 1px in all directions https://ibb.co/YjwRb9B

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on this post replies: (Swift 3)

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -1,
                                           y: -2,
                                           width: target.frame.width + 2,
                                           height: target.frame.height + 2))

target.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(hexString: shadowColor).cgColor
target.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(shadowOffsetX), height: CGFloat(shadowOffsetY))
target.layer.masksToBounds = false
target.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)
target.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Change a little bit from [@Senseful 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48489506/6071965) and works fine to my project.

- Support shadow corner radius (for some round corner view)
- `spread == 0` it still apply shadow effect(looks like border)

```
struct SketchShadow {
    var color: UIColor = .black
    let alpha: Float = 0.1
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
    let blur: CGFloat
    let spread: CGFloat
    let cornorRadius: CGFloat
    
    func applyToLayer(_ layer: CALayer) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = alpha
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
        layer.shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
        if spread == 0 {
            layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornorRadius, height: cornorRadius)).cgPath
        } else {
            let dx = -(spread)
            let rect = layer.bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
            layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornorRadius, height: cornorRadius)).cgPath
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like [the answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48489506/611879) and suggestions in the comments. This is how I modified that solution:

```
extension UIView {
  func applyShadow(color: UIColor, alpha: Float, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, blur: CGFloat, spread: CGFloat) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = alpha
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
    layer.shadowRadius = blur / UIScreen.main.scale
    if spread == 0 {
      layer.shadowPath = nil
    } else {
      let dx = -spread
      let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
      layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
    }
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```
myButton.applyShadow(color: .black, alpha: 0.2, x: 0, y: 1, blur: 2, spread: 0)
```