# Shadows in Swift are totally different than in Sketch

Tags: swift, sketchapp

Iam trying to apply shadow to `tableView` `cell`, which is rounded.

So the cell view's hierarchy is:

```
-TableView
 -Cell //height 85
  -ContentView //height 85
   -View //height 85
    -RoundedView //height 65
```

And this is how I am applying the shadow:

```
extension UIView{
    func dropShadow(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat, shadowRadius: CGFloat, color: CGColor, opacity: Float) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius //Give the view corner radius
        self.layer.shadowColor = color //Shadow color
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)//Offset like in Sketch X and Y
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius //It should be the blur in Sketch
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius)).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

These are the Sketch properties:

[image]
[image]

I have even exported the shadow color from Sketch:

```
cellShadow = UIColor(hue: 0.643, saturation: 0.061, brightness: 0.906, alpha: 0.5)//Alpha 0.5
```

And this is the output on iPhone:

[image]

And this is the design in Sketch:

[image]

Why the shadow cuts on iPhone and why the color is different a little(I am using color picker to see if it matches but it is not matching)? What I am doing wrong, can anybody tell me?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48489506

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control shadow spread and blur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269399/how-to-control-shadow-spread-and-blur)

Comment: @Dule no, my shadow is cut at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you have set the color to...

```
UIColor(hue: 0.643, saturation: 0.061, brightness: 0.906, alpha: 0.5)
```

This already includes the opacity from Sketch as Sketch defines the shadow opacity in the color.

Then you are doing this...

```
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Which then takes that color (with 50% opacity) and applies a 50% alpha to it. So now you effectively have a 25% opacity.

In defining the color set the alpha to 1. Not 0.5. That will darken the color.

You haven't shown how your other shadow properties are set up in Sketch so thats all I can advise for now.

**EDIT**

OK...

The colours look a lot better now.

The reason for the cut off is that your shadow radius is HUGE! (Seriously, does it need to be that big? Normally 4 or 6 will cut it. 20 is overkill.)

The reason this is happening is that the distance between the "content view" (the one with the shadow on it) and the edge of the cell is not enough to accommodate the full shadow.

You have an offset of 5 vertically and a radius of 20 so that means you'll need at least a distance of 25 from the bottom of the "content view" to the edge of the cell to fully display the shadow. (15 at the top... 20 - 5).

Another option is to disable `clipsToBounds` on the cell... `cell.clipsToBounds = false`. The downside to this is that your shadows may collide causing darker spots where the overlap.

TBH though, just reduce the radius and the problem disappears :D

Comment: I just noticed the same thing while I was asking the question then I changed all them but the result is the same, I am gonna edit the question with the right colors and the sketch properties.

Comment: My radius is that big because my colors are so light that it is pretty hard to understand where the cell is if there are no shadows at top also :D I tried to turn off the clipToBounds and in my situation, it makes perfect result. But at least I know the reason why it was cuting itself :D Thank you very much :)

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp no worries :D

Comment: So I guess another question is what does `shadowRadius` refer to? It's not the number of points that the shadow extends from the view, the shadow is always larger.

Comment: @JamesP the docs say "The blur radius (in points) used to render the layer’s shadow." I always assumed it was the length of the blur from the path to the edge. But it could be the "blur radius" parameter of a gaussian blur (or whichever blur function is used) applied to a line of the shadow color along the path of the shadow. I'm not too sure how a gaussian blur works though. Might be worth checking that out :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right about it being the gaussian blur radius. Blurring a box gives the same results as the shadow.