# How to get shadow in UIButton inside

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using below code for shadow in outside for UIButton. But how can i get shadow for inside the button

```
button.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: see this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   #define kDEFAULT_SHADOW_COLOR [UIColor lightGrayColor]   
   UIColor *color = [kDEFAULT_SHADOW_COLOR colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
        NSArray *colorsArray = @[(id)[color CGColor], (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
        CGFloat yOffset = 0.0f;
        CGFloat leftHeight = button.bounds.size.height;
        CAGradientLayer *shadow;
        shadow = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        shadow.colors = colorsArray;
        shadow.frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, 5.0, leftHeight);
        shadow.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
        shadow.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
        [button.layer insertSublayer:shadow atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the button shadows property. Add the following lines of code and show shadow. The Code is...

```
self.submitBtn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.submitBtn.layer.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.submitBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200.0f/255.0f) green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

self.submitBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;

self.submitBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
self.submitBtn.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

self.submitBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(100.0f/255.0f) green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.submitBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
self.submitBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
self.submitBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
```