# inner shadow effect UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to add inner shadow to this UIlabel

Picture:

[image: picture]

reference form [Inner shadow effect on UIView layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431292/inner-shadow-effect-on-uiview-layer)

```
    let display = UILabel()

func setBackgroundLayer () {
    let backgroundLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    backgroundLayer.frame = view.bounds
    backgroundLayer.colors = [UIColor(white:1,alpha:0.5).cgColor,UIColor(white:0.5,alpha:0.5).cgColor]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, at: 0)
}

func setDisplay() {
    let Xratio = view.bounds.width/8
    display.frame = CGRect(x:Xratio,y:80,width:Xratio*6,height:Xratio*2)
    display.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:204/255,green:203/255,blue:181/255,alpha:1)
    view.addSubview(display)

}

func displayInnerShadow() {


    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.frame = view.bounds

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(display.frame.insetBy(dx: -20, dy: -20))
    path.addRect(display.frame)


    shadowLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    shadowLayer.path = path

    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(white:0,alpha:1).cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0,height:0)
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5

    view.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 1)

 }



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setBackgroundLayer()
    setDisplay()
    //displayInnerShadow()
}
```

I got this result:

[image: result picture]

Why isn't it working and how to set the fill color?

Comment: "I want to add inner shadow to this UIlabel"  Where is the label?

Comment: sorry,, the UIlabel is just the green rect in the pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
let display = UILabel()

func setBackgroundLayer () {
    let backgroundLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    backgroundLayer.frame = view.bounds
    backgroundLayer.colors = [UIColor(white:1,alpha:0.5).cgColor,UIColor(white:0.5,alpha:0.5).cgColor]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, at: 0)
}

func setDisplay() {
    let Xratio = view.bounds.width/8
    display.frame = CGRect(x:Xratio,y:80,width:Xratio*6,height:Xratio*2)
```

set layer background color instead of display.backgroundColor

```
    display.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:204/255,green:203/255,blue:181/255,alpha:1).cgColor
    view.addSubview(display)

}

func displayInnerShadow() {

    let innerShadowLayer = CALayer()
    innerShadowLayer.frame = display.bounds
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: innerShadowLayer.bounds.insetBy(dx: -20, dy: -20))
    let innerPart = UIBezierPath(rect: innerShadowLayer.bounds).reversing()
    path.append(innerPart)
    innerShadowLayer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    innerShadowLayer.masksToBounds = true
    innerShadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    innerShadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    innerShadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    innerShadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
    display.layer.addSublayer(innerShadowLayer)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setDisplay()
    setBackgroundLayer()
    displayInnerShadow()

}
```

Comment: can you show the code after with implemented answer?

Comment: I update the question, I copy all you answer and change the 'label' to 'display'

Comment: of course, seeing the inner shadow, some position issue still fixing,shadow is in the left-top

Comment: it works great.. thanks.. position problem fixed by change innerShadowLayer.frame = display.bounds to display.frame